# Keeping Azure MARS backup after server deleted

Tags: backup, azure, azure-backup

An Azure Windows file server was backing up its files using the MARS agent into the recovery services vault and is listed as a protected server (see below). This server has been superseded but before I delete it, I want to check that the MARS backup will be preserved. My client needs to keep this historical backup for many years.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the VM has no effect on the backup itself. Also have a look [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms#stop-protecting-a-vm)

Even if you would delete the backup with all the recovery points the backup data would be retained for 14 additional days (assuming soft delete is enabled)